# PHP Extendware Crawler Error on Magento Site

Tags: php, magento

I'm having an issue while crawling the extendware ewcrawler.php file through command prompt like,

user@xxxx [/home/user/public_html/shell/extendware/ewcrawler]# php crawler.php -v

And getting an below error,

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 1792 bytes) in
>   /home/user/public_html/app/code/local/Extendware/EWCore/Model/Mage/Core/Abstract.php(45)
>   : eval()'d code on line 45

​Even the PHP_memory_limit is set to 512 MB on both config (php.ini and .htaccess)​ I have checked and tested after increasing the current memory_limit value also but still hitting to the same issue.

Can anyone please advise on the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the crawler is being run from a command line script, the php memory_limit will need to be increased for **the command line php interpreter**. This is **not** done from `.htaccess`. Where this is done is dependent on the Linux distro you are running, but there ususally will be separate php.ini files for Apache DSO, cgi-fpm, and command line.

Alternatively a memory directive can added to the script. Just remember that it will disappear the next time you apply an upgrade from Extendware.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Also, since this is a third party Magento module, you should be talking to Extendware about this as the developers often are a lot quicker at pinpointing problems with code they're intensely familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini changed as follows: `memory_limit = 512MB to memory_limit = 536870912.`

Comment: I have the server configured with WHM & CPanel its not allowed me to set the value in bytes.

Comment: then change 512MB to 512M

Comment: did you change in php ini and ,htaccess too?

Comment: change it to -1 for unlimited time last option

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to .htaccess file in Magento root try to increase memory there

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Comment: I have increased on .htaccess but no luck.

Comment: @sudhakaranR87 Is this VPS server or shared hosting? Does it has suhosin installed on it? Do you have access to php.ini file?

Comment: Its dedicated server and suhosin is not installed on the server also I have access to the php.ini file.